# How to input an array that has several inputs through a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have the following code that decyphers encrypted texts:

```
letter = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
path = 'Cipher Assignment/ciphertext*.txt'
ciphers = glob.glob("Cipher Assignment/ciphertext*.txt")
keys = glob.glob("Cipher Assignment/key*.txt")
arrayCipher = []
arrayKey = []

# Function that opens files and saves them into an array:
def savingFiles(inputFiles, sourceFiles):
    for sourceFile in sourceFiles:
        with open(sourceFile) as ins:
            for line in ins:
                inputFiles.append(line)
    return inputFiles

arrayCiphers = savingFiles(arrayCipher, ciphers)
arrayKeys = savingFiles(arrayKey, keys)
```

How do I input my 2 arrays (arrayCiphers, arrayKeys) to be decoded in the decode function?

```
# Decoding function that decyphers the text:
def decode(ciphertext, key, letter):
    indexKey = dict(zip(key, letter))
    return ''.join(indexKey.get(c.lower(), c) for c in ciphertext)


# for i in range(len(arrayKeys)):
#     decoded = decode(arrayCiphers, arrayKeys[i], letter)
#     print(decoded)

for index, key in enumerate(arrayKey):
    decoded = decode(arrayCiphers[index], key, letter)
    print(decoded)
```

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by input? Do you mean passing them into the decode?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: it means `def decode (arrayCiphers, arrayKeys , letter) `?

Comment: I'm trying to pass both arrays through the decoding function. The problem I'm having is that arrayCiphers[0] should use arrayKeys[0], arrayCiphers[1] should use arrayKeys[1] and so on.